# Почему не работает цикл PHP?

Tags: php

Имеется следующий PHP код, цикл не хочет запускаться по какой-то причине, описанной в ошибке. PHP говорит, что нужно поставить запятую или точку с запятой, но я и так поставил.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in W:\domains\test.loc\index.php on line 31

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="form-container">
  <h1 class="headline">
   Make your order
  </h1>
  <p class='light-description'>
   Fill the inputs for your order.
  </p>
  <form action="index.php" method='GET'>
   <div class="input-container">
    <h2 class='input-name'>Name</h2>
    <input type="text" name='name' placeholder='Name'>
   </div>
   <?php
   
    $inputs = ['First Name', 'Second Name', 'Phone', 'Email'];
    $inputsNames = ['firstName', 'secondName', 'phone', 'email'];

    
    for($i = 0; $i < inputs.count; $i++) {
     echo '<div class="input-container"';
     echo '<h2 class="input-name">'.$inputs[i].'</h2>';
     echo '<input type="text" name="'.$inputsNames[i].'" placeholder="'.$inputs[i].'">';
     echo '</div>'
    };

   ?>
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А в последнем echo где ; ?

Comment: Вы с этим перепутали - `inputs.count`, не должно ли быть `count($inputs)`?

Comment: @Hikikomori, ошибка пропала, но цикл ничего не вывел. (Если прописать просто echo '1'; в начале, то единицу выводит

Comment: `echo '</div>'` точку с запятой поставьте, ошибка говорит что не может понять где заканчивается цикл

Comment: И `};` тут надо убрать

Comment: Даже сама ошибка говорит на какой строке, почему........

Comment: @Walfter, зачем убирать }; ?

Comment: @entithat, спасибо, помогло, я просто перепутал с синтаксисом js'a немного. Но теперь пробелема в том, что не вывелись вообще элемента массива.

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi, ибо надо указывать `$i`, a не `i`..

Comment: @entithat, спасибо больше, еще путаюсь :)

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi, пожалуйста, бывает:)

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi вы как бы интерпритатору говорите тут конецконец

Comment: @Walfter, ну это не критично, ведь код запускается и так без каких-либо ошибок или предупреждений.

Comment: @entithat я хотел сказать что это не красиво и только, пропустил "бы".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кроме ошибки с `;`, о которой сказали в комментариях у Вас неверно записано кол-во инпутов: `inputs.count`. Если Вы хотели указать кол-во элементов массива `$inputs`, то надо было так: `count($inputs)`.

Вот код, который будет работать:

```
$inputs = ['First Name', 'Second Name', 'Phone', 'Email'];
$inputsNames = ['firstName', 'secondName', 'phone', 'email'];


for($i = 0; $i < count($inputs); $i++) {
    echo '<div class="input-container"';
    echo '<h2 class="input-name">' . $inputs[$i] . '</h2>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="' . $inputsNames[$i] . '" placeholder="' . $inputs[$i] . '">';
    echo '</div>';
}
```